# How to get the text before & after the hyperlink using Selenium and Xpath

Tags: selenium, xpath, webdriverwait, textnode, execute-script

I am trying to find cases using Xpath/Selenium where there is no white-space before the hyperlink.

e.g.

```
<p>Click on this<a href="#">link</a>to access the data</p>`
```

This renders as `Click on thislinkto access the data`

**Problem :** Locate all the `<a>` elements and test if they have white-space before and after

Is there any elegant way to get the text before/after of anchor? I am thinking of using XPath query such as `//a/parent::*` which returns `<p>` element but the `<a>` tag is not separated. Can I somehow get the immediate text before/after the anchor tag?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using selenium, I'm assuming xpath 1.0.

This should select `a` elements that don't have a preceding or following space...

```xml
//a[substring(preceding-sibling::text()[1],string-length(preceding-sibling::text()[1]) )!=' ' or substring(following-sibling::text()[1],1,1)!=' ']
```

Comment: instead of `substring(preceding-sibling::text()[1],string-length(preceding-sibling::text()[1]) )!=' '` use this: `[preceding-sibling::text()[1][substring(.,string-length(.) )!=' ']`

Answer (score 0):

As per the HTML, there are two *text nodes* with text *`Click on this`* and *`to access the data`* and a *`<a>`* element within their parent 



 element.

```
<p>
    Click on this
    <a href="#">link</a>
    to access the data
</p>
```

---

### Solution

To print *text* before the `<a>` element you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *Python*, *XPATH*, *childNodes* and `strip()`:

  ```
  print(driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].firstChild.textContent;', WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(., 'link')]//ancestor::p[1]")))).strip())
  ```
- Using *Python*, *XPATH*, `get_attribute()` and `splitlines()`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(., 'link')]//ancestor::p[1]"))).get_attribute("innerHTML").splitlines()[1])
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```